# Writing custom Prepare Scripts for Open Data Cube?

Tags: raster, imagery, satellite, file-formats, open-data-cube

How do I write custom prepare scripts for the [Open Data Cube](https://www.opendatacube.org) format ?

---

The [docs](https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ops/prepare_scripts.html#custom-prepare-scripts) say the following:

> We expect that many new Data Cube instances will require custom prepare scripts to be written. It is generally a straightforward task of mapping metadata from one form to another and writing out a YAML document.

That's it.

Also the [official training center](https://www.odc-training.org/documentation-tutorials) is not helpful as it does not say *anything* about it.

---

Can someone explain this a bit more in detail or does someone have better sources or tutorial(s) other than analyzing the  non-commented [sample prepare scripts](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-core/tree/develop/utils) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the [official documentation](http://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/intro.html) of [`datacube-core`](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-core) is not yet very useful, the project owner CEOS has a much better documentation hidden in another github project named [`CEOS Data Cube UI`](https://github.com/ceos-seo/data_cube_ui).

- [Ingestion Guide](https://github.com/ceos-seo/data_cube_ui/blob/master/docs/ingestion_guide.md)

The topic I was looking for can be found [here](https://github.com/ceos-seo/data_cube_ui/blob/master/docs/ingestion_guide.md#-generating-metadata).

---

I will not copy-paste the whole documentation. But the following is the information the prepare script should output to a `yaml` file:

```
creation_dt: '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
extent:
  center_dt: '2014-03-01 11:59:59'
  coord:
    ll: {lat: -90.0000031, lon: -179.99999689999999}
    lr: {lat: -90.0000031, lon: 180.0000031}
    ul: {lat: 89.9999969, lon: -179.99999689999999}
    ur: {lat: 89.9999969, lon: 180.0000031}
  from_dt: '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
  to_dt: '2014-03-01 23:59:59'
format: {name: GeoTiff}
grid_spatial:
  projection:
    geo_ref_points:
      ll: {x: -179.9999969, y: -90.0000031}
      lr: {x: 180.0000031, y: -90.0000031}
      ul: {x: -179.9999969, y: 89.9999969}
      ur: {x: 180.0000031, y: 89.9999969}
    spatial_reference: GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
id: e95ed0b5-ac2b-4c59-9aa8-2b3f0cd2ef40
image:
  bands:
    ice_precipitation: {path: 3B-MO-GIS.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20140301-S000000-E235959.03.V04A.ice.tif}
    liquid_precipitation: {path: 3B-MO-GIS.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20140301-S000000-E235959.03.V04A.liquid.tif}
    percent_liquid: {path: 3B-MO-GIS.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20140301-S000000-E235959.03.V04A.liquidPercent.tif}
    total_precipitation: {path: 3B-MO-GIS.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20140301-S000000-E235959.03.V04A.tif}
instrument: {name: GPM}
lineage:
  source_datasets: {}
platform: {code: GPM}
processing_level: V04A
product_type: monthly
```

---