# Open Data Cube how to continue after the creation of the database?

Tags: python, python-3, open-data-cube

I have some questions about using Open Data Cube. First of all I have successfully installed the virtual environment with miniconda and the database with PostgreSQLPortable-10.1.1.

Now I have already used the ingest command to initialize the database with .yaml files (always following the online guide) such as bom_rainfall_grids.yaml etc ..

Now I don't really know how to continue a UI exists? How do I get images processed?

Comment: did you see my question from awhile ago or are you already at the next step ? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289968/writing-custom-prepare-scripts-for-open-data-cube

Comment: I read your topic and it seems that I am far behind. In short, I do not even know how to take pictures to use or run an example provided by them.

Comment: In step 3 I am having this problem.[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0sse.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0sse.png)

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that you have set the datacube up (test that with datacube system check). Otherwise, get started with the following doc, cross-checking whether you've completed all the steps mentioned in it! [CEOS-SEO - Get Started](https://github.com/ceos-seo/data_cube_ui/blob/master/docs/start_here.md)

Step 1 :- Download Satellite images. Choose a dataset. e.g. Landsat 8 level 1. It can be downloaded from [USGS Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/).  extract them within /datacube/original_data/Folder_Name_based_on_Instrument_Path_row_acquisition_date.

Step 2 :- Add the [Landsat 8 level 1 product](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-core/blob/develop/docs/config_samples/dataset_types/ls_usgs.yaml) using the following command :-

```
datacube product add ~/Datacube/datacube-core/docs/config_samples/dataset_types/ls_usgs.yaml
```

Step 3 :- Prepare the metadata file for the image you downloaded.

```
python ~/Datacube/datacube-core/utils/ls_usgs_prepare.py --output /datacube/original_data/folder_containing_satellite_images/ls8_usgs_lv1.yaml /datacube/original_data/folder_containing_satellite_images/
```

P.S:- you can use wildcard, for example, look up the guide added below as reference. this will create ls8_usgs_lv1.yaml in the folder which contains the satellite images. this can be any other filename too, and is datacube-metadata.yaml in the guide and the script mentioned works for Landsat 7 level 2 data.

Step 4 :- index the metadata file created just now

```
datacube -v dataset add /datacube/original_data/Folder1/ls8_usgs_lv1.yaml
```

Step 5:- Prepare an ingest script for your dataset. there are some entries which should match the dataset / product you added.

Instructions on preparing the script can be found in the following section :-
[CEOS - Ingestion guide](https://github.com/ceos-seo/data_cube_ui/blob/master/docs/ingestion.md#-ingesting-datasets)

ingest the script you do create with the command :-

```
datacube -v ingest -c ~/Folder1/.../ingest_script_created.yaml
```

References :-

- [CEOS-SEO Ingestion guide](https://github.com/ceos-seo/data_cube_ui/blob/master/docs/ingestion_guide.md)
- [Datacube core readthedocs](https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ops/prepare_scripts.html)

Comment: How did you create the configuration files after the PostgreSQL database creation?